# Is the DES F-function injective for a given subkey?

Tags: des, s-boxes, feistel-network

Is it possible for two different half-block inputs to the [DES F-function](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#The_Feistel_.28F.29_function), with the same round subkey, to produce the same output?

That is, if we feed two different half-block inputs $b_1$ and $b_2$ through the expansion stage, XOR them with a constant subkey $K$, and then pass the expanded and XORed inputs through the S-boxes, is it possible for the outputs $o_1 = F(b_1, K)$ and $o_2 = F(b_2,K)$ to be equal?

Comment: We just had [a very similar (but apparently not duplicate) question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/des-generating-the-same-ciphertext-for-different-plaintexts-and-identical-key) less than 24 hours earlier. Just out of idle curiosity, are these coming from some online course or something, or is it just a remarkable coincidence?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can; within the DES round function, two different 'right side' inputs can, after the sboxes, come up with the same value to xor into the 'left side'.

This was a deliberate decision by the DES designers, who thought that this was an important property.  I don't know their reasoning about why they thought it was important.

Comment: Does that make a _yes_ answer to this related question: [_DES f function injective for no fixed subkey?_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/81062/555).

Answer (score 0):

A decade or so ago I wrote something to explore what values could be produced by f(R,K) for a particular key.

`eightbox -K c034a483 -E c034a485
K=11XX00_00XX00_00XX11_01XX00_10XX10_01XX00_10XX00_00XX11
S=c04212b2  B=5a02d23ca0a1   S[1-8]Row=0,2,1,0,1,0,0,3  1
S=c04212b2  B=553c7a3ca0a1   S[1-8]Row=1,1,3,2,1,0,0,3  2
S=c04212b2  B=ca02d23ca15f   S[1-8]Row=2,2,1,0,1,0,1,1  3
K=11XX00_00XX00_00XX11_01XX00_10XX10_01XX00_10XX00_01XX00
S=c04212b2  B=5a02d23ca142   S[1-8]Row=0,2,1,0,1,0,1,0  1
S=c04212b2  B=553c7a3ca142   S[1-8]Row=1,1,3,2,1,0,1,0  2
K=11XX00_00XX00_00XX11_01XX00_10XX10_01XX00_10XX00_01XX01
S=c04212b2  unused 1
loops = 3, unused = 1, maxused = 3`

The value `B` is the 48 input to the eight S boxes comprised of E(R) xor K.

The command line arguments to eightbox represent the starting key and ending key for the 32 bits of key influencing S box inputs affected by shared R bits due to the Expansion permutation.

eighbox takes a candidate range of sbox outputs (`S`, in this case a single value 0xc04212b2) and a range of key values for the shared E(R) bits and determines the input values (`B`) that can produced `S`.

For the three candidate key values we get 3, 2 and 0 output values for `S=c04212b2` (a default target single S box output).

It tells us not only can we have duplicate f(R,K) outputs for a fixed K, but some S box outputs are not possible for some values of K.

The remaining 16 bits of K have no other dependencies than the value of unshared R bits. Setting those K values further restricts the value of R to one possibility for each candidate value of `B`.

The knowledge is of limited usefulness because we can't see the S Box outputs directly, instead requiring things like Differential Cryptanalysis and it's three round deterministic, dependent on the number of shared K bits between rounds.

So yes it's possible to satisfy the criteria *outputs o1=F(b1,K) and o2=F(b2,K) to be equal* as the above proves. (And proofs are nice.)

There's sufficient information in the above to produce an entire 48 bit K value and matching R values for the 'collisions'.  I don't think I've seen more than 8 different R values producing the same `S` output, I'd have to dig through any collected data to check or re-run over a range of `S` and/or `K` values.  I may not have printed out the K value previously, I had to enable it for the above.