# Finding collisions for the DES F-function

Tags: encryption, collision-resistance, des

It's known that for a given subkey, the F-function of the DES is not injective (see [Is the DES F-function injective for a given subkey?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/21088/is-the-des-f-function-injective-for-a-given-subkey)). I am interested in efficiently finding collisions for this function, i.e. for a given subkey $k$, I want to find two different inputs $x$ and $y$ such that $F(x,k)=F(y,k)$.

I am wondering if there are shortcuts that make finding such key values easier than plain brute-force?

Comment: Hint: $F(x,k)$ is the concatenation of 8 independent 4-bit functions of 6-bit extracts of $x$ and $k$. Further, these extracts are combined by XOR.

Answer (score 1):

If S is a DES S-box, for a given "output", S(input) = output has exctly 4 solutions for "input", or "collisions". You can then find collisions for F by concatenating collisions for each S-box.
You can start with setting an output for F and then look for all possible "inputs" for each of the 8 S-boxes on the 4 relevant bits of the output of F.